# How to partial match words within a string - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table called Keywords that 100's of keywords ranging from one word to several, all separated by commas. For example:

```
change of name, asb, repair, reporting violence
```

These keywords are grouped into categories.

We have users who can enter any text into a free text field. Example:

```
Caller rang to to speak to ASB about violence
```

How do I use SQL to read the words in the free text field to check for any matches in the keyword table? So in the example above I want it to pick up that ASB and Violence was stored in the Keyword table.

I would also want it bring back a result if only one word was used like ASB.

It's important to note that any words could be entered into the free text field.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP2.

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Hi, Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP2

Comment: I would use a Full Text Catalog and read up more on that.  MS recommends when you start getting into a lot of text searching to do it this way.  If you are only doing it for a few things and a small database it is probably okay.  But in the end if it for a full featured core part of an application it is a more full featured set meant for this type of operation.  Also you can do similar searches like bike = bicycle and vice versa.  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Answer (score 0):

As you have not specified your table names; I will create some.  Please run this:

```
create table dbWords (id int not null identity, words varchar(100), primary key (id))
insert into dbWords (words) values ('change of name, asb, repair, reporting violence')

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
ENd
```

Then run this:

```
    select * from dbWords inner join (
select * from dbo.fnSplitString('change of name, change of dob', ',')
) as splitdatatable on dbwords.words like '%,' + splitdata+ ',%'
or dbwords.words like '%,' + splitdata
or dbwords.words like splitdata + ',%'
```

The text passed to the function in the SQL statement above is the text entered by the user.

Comment: Hi I have Microsoft SQL server 2014 SP2. Ref the structure - I'm reading data from one table and one column which returns multiple rows. Each row has a list of keywords separated by a comma

Comment: @user114790, please post the structure of your table

Comment: @user114790, I have edited my answer now I know you are using SQL Server 2014.